# Compilation error on List.getFirst(): cannot find symbol?

Tags: java

Could you detect a problem of compilation? It compiles locally without any errors. But it fails when it was compiled using a distant autocode service over which I have no influence.

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /tmp/builds/autocode_133386/src/main/java/com/classes/ArrayRectangles.java:[76,46] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFirst()
  location: variable perimeters of type java.util.List<java.lang.Double>
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.849 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-17T07:57:25Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Classes: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /tmp/builds/autocode_133386/src/main/java/com/classes/ArrayRectangles.java:[76,46] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method getFirst()
[ERROR]   location: variable perimeters of type java.util.List<java.lang.Double>
```

my code

```
List<Double> perimeters = new ArrayList<>();
...
double minPerim = perimeters.getFirst(); // error is here
```

pom file

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <junit5.version>5.8.2</junit5.version>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: there is no "getFirst()" method in the List interface. How did you get that to compile locally?

Comment: @Stultuske then how it compiles locally? how it passes all tests locally?

Comment: My guess: it doesn't.

Comment: It compiles locally because you're compiling with JDK 21 but you're compiling with an older JDK on the server (where the method getFirst was not yet in the List interface)?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ it makes sence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method [getFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#getFirst()) has been added to the `List` interface starting from JDK 21.

It is highly possible that your code compiles locally because you're using a JDK 21, but not on server because the server is using an image with an older JDK where the method is not yet declared.

Solutions:

- (Long term): You upgrade your server to JDK 21
- (Short term): Replace `List.getFirst()` by `List.get(0)`, paying the right attention to when the list is empty (in that case, `get(0)` would raise an out of bound exception so you need to check the `.size()` first and return `null` (or throw an exception, as the current implementation of `getFirst()` does), if the list is empty.